# Disable the Horizontal ScrollBar from ListView in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollable

In my application I'm using lots of ListView's for many purposes. I want to disable the Horizontal ScrollBar. Which I have done effectively using the following links as references
[Disable Horizontal ScrollBar 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4aa4dade-53a2-4e2e-a8b4-b4980da1f39c/hide-horizontal-scrollbar-in-listview?forum=winforms) , [Disable Horizontal ScrollBar 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466979/c-sharp-listview-disable-horizontal-scrollbar). The following is my code:

First of all I set the Scrollable Property of the ListView to false

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static public extern bool ShowScrollBar(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);
private const uint SB_HORZ = 0; //Horrizontal Scroll
private const uint SB_VERT = 1; //Vertical Scroll
private const uint ESB_DISABLE_BOTH = 0x3;
private const uint ESB_ENABLE_BOTH = 0x0;
```

Created a method so as to use it for all the ListView's throught the application

```
public  void HideHorizontalScrollBar(ListView lv,int value, bool isNeeded)
{
    ShowScrollBar(lv.Handle, value, isNeeded);
}
```

Now referenced this method inside the Contructor of the MainForm just after the InitializeComponent()

```
 private void ListViewHorrizontalScrollBar()
{
    //0 for horrizontal
    //1 for vertical

    _ListViewScrollOperation.HideHorizontalScrollBar(this.lvAntSetExcludedFiles, 0, false);
    _ListViewScrollOperation.HideHorizontalScrollBar(this.lvAntSetExcludedFiles, 1, true);
}
```

Now this thing works perfectly for me. However I just have a small problem. Even if there are Only 2 Values still the Vertical ScrollBar is visible. Even if there isnt any data in the ListView still the Vertical ScrollBar is Visible.

[image]

Also I'm not able to navigate from Top-Bottom or from Bottom-Top using the Up and Down arrow keys of the Keyboard since the Scrollable Property of the ListView is set to false.
So is there anything else that I can do to tackle with the Issue?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Are you trying to disable horizontal scrollbar, because you set column header too long?

Comment: @Sinatr I tried changing the Column Header many times but still was facing the issue so only i posted over here.

Comment: Try to use [auto-size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1257500/1997232) column width.

Answer (score -1):

After much of Googling and little hint from [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) I finally came up with the solution. And of course as the comment states I was in a  [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So this is what I did.

- I first changed the Scrollable property of the ListView to true.
- Removed the Chunk of codes that I mentioned above in my question.

And here is the extra lines of code that I added just after the ListView

```
lv.Items.Clear();
foreach (string newval in stringlist)
    lv.Items.Add(newval);
lv.Columns[0].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);
lv.Columns[0].Width = 'Your own size';
lv.Columns[0].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

Doing which I achieved the following things

- Disabled Horizontal ScrollBar
- Navigation Using Up-Down arrows
- The vertical ScrollBar doesnot appear unwantedly.