# Determine height of ListBox required to remove vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Say I have a `ListBox` control having ID `myList`, to which I've added 50 items. The vertical scrollbar is inevitably displayed on the right-side of the control. Two related questions:

1. How do I determine at runtime what value to set `myList.Height` to
   so that the scrollbar will NOT be displayed?
2. How do I determine the height that one row requires (with padding)?

The value of `myList.ClientSize.Height` changes if the font is changed (for internationalisation), so this needs to be dynamic when the form loads.

Note: If you are wondering "Why remove the scrollbar?", I intend to handle scrolling separately by placing the `ListBox` on a parent control and modifying `myList.Top` in response to clicks on Up/Down Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [C# ListView Disable Horizontal Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466979/c-sharp-listview-disable-horizontal-scrollbar)

For compact framework this has to be changed to

```
[DllImport ("coredll")]
private static extern long ShowScrollBar (long hwnd , long wBar, long bShow);
long SB_HORZ = 0;
long SB_VERT = 1;
long SB_BOTH = 3;

private void HideHorizontalScrollBar ()
{
    ShowScrollBar(listView1.Handle.ToInt64(), SB_HORZ, 0);
}
private void HideScrollBars ()
{
    ShowScrollBar(listView1.Handle.ToInt64(), SB_BOTH, 0);
}
```

There is another solution at [How to hide the vertical scroll bar in a .NET ListView Control in Details mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488622/how-to-hide-the-vertical-scroll-bar-in-a-net-listview-control-in-details-mode), again: replace user32 by coredll for compact framework/Windows Mobile 6.x

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as `coredll.dll` does not export the `ShowScrollbar` method. In managed applications which make some use of `P/Invoke` it is sensible to call `Marshal.PrelinkAll(this.GetType());` early in the application life to confirm all `P/Invoke` methods are available. My application immediately throws an exception for `ShowScrollbar`.

Comment: A nice workaround, suggested in this article: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/hiding-vertical-scrollbar-in-listbox.2890942/, is to simply limit the number of items in the ListBox or ListView so that no scrollbar is required. You then just change a page number and update the view to scroll up or down.

Comment: -1 for showing answer that uses API that is not available on Windows CE: ShowScrollBar is not supported on Windows CE 5 based OS.

Comment: You may write a custom control that behaves like a list box: see here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24048/Implementing-a-smoothly-animated-ListBox

Comment: I'm confused. Your answer uses `ShowScrollBar` which is not available on CE 5.0 and 6.0. Then you comment to say "-1 for showing answer that uses API that is not available on Windows CE"...about your own answer. What am I missing?