# Hide both scroll bars in a Windows.Forms.Listview

Tags: c#, listview

I'm using this code to hide the vertical bar in a listview
[Hide vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488622/how-to-hide-the-vertical-scroll-bar-in-a-net-listview-control-in-details-mode)

But I have found no way to hide both bars, horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Have you tried with WS_HSCROLL too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ListView Disable Horizontal Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466979/c-sharp-listview-disable-horizontal-scrollbar)

Comment: Why -1? It is not a duplicate, my question is different, if you read it, vertical and both is not the same thing.

Comment: Not work, i receive this error (translate with Google)
A call to the PInvoke function 'Flyevo! Flyevo.Leo :: ShowScrollBar' has unbalanced the stack. This problem may occur when the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged destination signature. Verify that the calling convention and the PInvoke signature parameters match the unmanaged destination signature.