# Hide scrollbars in ListView and keep it Scrollable

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollbar

I am trying to hide a `ListView`'s scrollbars and keep it scrollable.
The reason for this is the design. They are very ugly!

When I turn `Scrollable` to `false` it will do actually hide the scrollbars which is my 1st goal but the `ListView` doesn't scroll. So is there a way to hide the scrollbars and keep it scrollable?

I found something here: [How to hide the vertical scroll bar in a .NET ListView Control in Details mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488622/how-to-hide-the-vertical-scroll-bar-in-a-net-listview-control-in-details-mode) but I can't get it working.

Comment: As a workaround to hide scrollbars but keep the `ListView` scrollable, you can wrap the list view in a `Panel` and set the `Location` of `ListView` to `(0,0)` and its `Height` same as panel and its `Width` wider than panel enough to hide vertical scrollbars. Also set the `Anchor` of your `ListView` to all sides. Also you can set the location, size, z-order, anchor and dock of panel to keep its positioning like listview. You can do this using designer or using a method.

Comment: The code in the referenced question works fine. What problem are you having?