# How to make two listviews scroll synchronously with one another in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listviewitem, synchronize

I have listview1 and listview2, and want to make it so that when one is scrolled, the other also scrolls synchronously. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronized ListViews in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159864/synchronized-listviews-in-net)

Comment: Refer to this link - http://www.gbogea.com/2009/07/08/how-to-keep-two-scrollviewers-in-sync-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in the `OnScroll()` method of `OnScrollListener`:

```
if (this.getScrollY() != otherList.getScrollY())
    otherList.setScrollY(this.getScrollY());
```

Another way, always implementing an AbsListView.OnScrollListener is that, when the ListView is scrolled, the `OnScroll()` method of `OnScrollListener` calls `SmoothScrollToPosition()` on the other ListView to synchronize to the same position.

[This article](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t34807-no-message-listview-scroll.aspx) and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39244/Scroll-Synchronization) are implementing another approach, a little bit more complicated, that consists of creating a custom control.